# Mean path length for light traversing a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am trying to estimate the mean length travelled by light rays in a cylinder irradiated from its sides. As a rough estimate, we assume irradiation to be direct (parallel to the y-axis) and neglect all reflection/refraction phenomena that might happen at the cylinder surface.  Basically, that would involve calculating the average "length" of a number *n* of perpendicular lines joining two points of the circumference.

Does anyone have any idea of a better approach to come up with this average length?

Comment: The mean length is 0, since most light rays don't hit the cylinder.  Are you asking for the mean length, conditioned on the event that the light ray hits the cylinder? Or something else? What is your probability distribution on the light rays?

Comment: When you say parallel to the $y$ axis, is that transverse to the cylinder axis?

Comment: A diagram would help in understanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

Place the circular cross section at the origin, measure in units of the radius, and consider vertical rays, parallel to the $y$ axis.  Given the $x$ point where the ray hits the axis, the length going through the cyclinder is $2\sqrt {1-x^2}$.  The average over all the rays that hit the cylinder is then $$\frac{\int_{-1}^12\sqrt{1-x^2}dx}{\int_{-1}^1dx}=\frac \pi 2$$